# Built-in function to get the angle between a vector and positive x axis - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the angle between a vector and positive x axis in Matlab by using a built-in function.

For example, if I have a=[-1 -1], i'd like to get 5pi/4 or 3.926.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function that does exactly that, but `atan2` is close enough: it provides

> the four quadrant arctangent of the elements of X and Y
>       such that -pi <= atan2(Y,X) <= pi

```
 atan2(-1,-1) %=-2.3562
```

So you only have to take care of the <0 case, when the angle is in the 3rd or 4th Quadrant (which it is in your case).

```
a=[-1,-1];
angle_to_xaxis = angleatan2(a(2),a(1))          %=-2.3562
if angle_to_xaxis < 0                           
    angle_to_xaxis = angle_to_xaxis + 2pi       %= 3.9270
end
```

If you have to calculate the angle multiple times, you might want to make a function out of it rather than having to check each time with an if:

```
Findangletoxaxis = @(a) mod(atan2(a(2),a(1)),2*pi); %anonymous function
a=[-1,-1];
Findangletoxaxis(a)
```

`mod` results are always positive if the divisor is positive. Thanks to @Cris Luengo

Comment: Or simply `mod(atan2(y,x),2*pi)`

Comment: @Finn thank you so much for your very useful solution.

Comment: Hello @CrisLuengo I like a lot your suggestion.